# Suitable technology for very small user base

Tags: project-management

My friend wants a way to organize her projects and tasks better at work.  She would like to be able to:

- Define Projects
- Define (Weekly) Tasks for each Project

  - A Task is associated with a particular week (day/time granularity not needed)
- Define Sub-Tasks for each Task
- View a week's worth of tasks and their subtasks at a time
- Zoom in to see a particular task in more detail
- Zoom out to see a whole month's tasks in less detail

And last, but not least, she would like to share this data with her supervisor, so he can see it and make comments / adjustments.

I'd like to know what options are available and the pros/cons of each...  I've considered:

- Excel sheet

  - Pros: easy to share, availability (she and her boss both have Excel installed)
  - Cons: harder to maintain and create multiple views of the same data.
- Access

  - Pros: easy to share (perhaps via storage on shared drive), availability
  - Cons: UI options not very rich, in my opinion
- .NET with local db file

  - Pros: Rich UI options, quick development (i am most familiar with .NET)
  - Cons: Availability - they would both have to have my app installed, or it would have to live on a shared drive somewhere (which is probably an option I guess...)

Can anybody shed any light on this as far as available options, pros/cons I haven't thought of for these or any other technologies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**www.trello.com** is the answer made by creators of Stackoverflow.com. I know I'm replying to a very old question. But it can be useful for those who will come across this page here on.

Also check out **[JIRA](http://atlassian.com/software/jira/overview)**.  JIRA is the project tracker for teams planning, building and launching great products. Its not a free solution but really effective.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is a great tool for this kind of thing. We use it in our development team for our iteration status. At least, when your sole user hits pain points, you'll see what your real pain points are before starting to code something in .NET/Ruby/Java/etc., and it will therefore serve as a useful prototype.